# H2 Embedded Mode - DELETE command giving COLUMN NOT FOUND error

Tags: java, sql, h2

I am kinda new to H2 DB and from what I saw in several examples and the official documentation, I managed to get a connection started and INSERT values into the DB.
Now, the DELETE command keeps giving me a COLUMN NOT FOUND error [42122] each time and the entry is not deleted.
This error happens only when using the conditional DELETE statement and not while deleting all entries from the table.

The table was created as follows

`CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE(NAME VARCHAR(40), NUMBER INT);`

My Java code is as follows

```
try {

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
    System.out.println("CONNECTED");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    if (remember_entry.isSelected()) {
        String add_entry = "INSERT INTO SCHEDULE VALUES ('" + name + "'," + number + ")";
        System.out.println(add_entry);
        stat.execute(add_entry);
        System.out.println("ENTRY ADDED");
    } else if (!remember_entry.isSelected()) {
        String remove_entry = "DELETE FROM SCHEDULE WHERE NAME = '" + name + "' AND number = " + number;
        System.out.println(remove_entry);
        stat.execute(remove_entry);
        System.out.println("ENTRY REMOVED");
    }
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the schedule table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE(NAME VARCHAR(40), NUMBER INT);

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please help. I have added your required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured things out myself.

Here is the updated line of code in Java.

`String remove_show = "DELETE FROM SCHEDULE WHERE NAME = '" + name + "' AND NUMBER = " + number;`

Somehow, this just works. I don't know what I was doing wrong, but it's fixed. :)